# Making an Array out of 4 objects instead of individual objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am trying to change four individual `DigitalCamera` objects into an array of four `DigitalCamera` objects, here is the code, I couldn't get it, any suggestions?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestDigitalCamera
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  DigitalCamera camera1;
  DigitalCamera camera2;
  DigitalCamera camera3;
  DigitalCamera camera4;

  camera1 = getData();
  camera2 = getData();
  camera3 = getData();
  camera4 = getData();

  camera1.display();
  camera2.display();
  camera3.display();
  camera4.display(); 
}
  public static DigitalCamera getData()
  {
  String brand;
  int megapixels;
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter camera brand ");
  brand = in.nextLine();
  System.out.print("Enter megapixels ");
  megapixels = in.nextInt();
  in.nextLine();
  DigitalCamera c = new DigitalCamera(brand, megapixels);
  return c;

  }
```

Comment: DigitalCamera[] cameras = ...

Answer (score 4):

Just create an array and use a loop. Try this:

```
DigitalCamera[] cameraArray = new DigitalCamera[4];
for(DigitalCamera camera:cameraArray) {
   camera = getData();
   camera.display();
}
```

Comment: it will throw nullPointerException.

Comment: @Trying Why ? getData is creating & returning a camera object.

Comment: you have initialized the array but not the object itself.

Comment: @Trying camera = getData  is actually the initialization of object.

Comment: @Trying when I made the array i get about 10 errors "Cannot find symbol symbol:   class DigitalCamera
  location: class TestDigitalCamera

Comment: @user2966818 Hope you have that class in your project or in a jar. If es, then just import that class in your test class.